# Calculation of final temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, experimental-physics, temperature, thermal-conductivity

what would be the final temperature of any body with the change in the ambient temperature?

A Body temperature was recorded at 27.2°C ambient temperature is 60.2°C

Final temperature of body is  60.2°C at 27.2°C ambient temperature.

Temperature Rise= Final Temp. recorded- Ambient Temp.
                      (60.2-27.2)
Temperature Rise- 33K

If I want to calculate the the final temp of the body with respect to 50°C ambient temperature. Is the below calculation is possible to calculate the final temp.

final temperature of body at ambient 50°C= ambient Temp+ the temperature rise

```
                                 e.g.50°C + 33K = 83°C
```

Is the above temperature calculations are correct or not?

Comment: The final temperature of an isolated body in an environment at 27.2 degrees is 27.2 degrees. Assuming a large environment >> than the body...

Comment: @jmh I'm not sure that is what the OP is asking. I think the question has to do with whether or not the final temperature of something that is heated and that was initially at ambient temperature can be specified as the sum of the ambient temperature + temperature rise.

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. Or at least not clear to me.  Could you please edit you question to make it clearer?

Comment: @jmh I agree it is still unclear. But since I have experience dealing with absolute vs temperature rises when testing products, I'm going to post an answer under the assumption (perhaps wrong) that that is the  issue here. Thanks.

Comment: @SalimShaikh Are you asking if it is possible to predict the temperature on the body in the 50 C ambient based on the temperature rise in the 27.2 C ambient?

Comment: @Mr. Bob. Thank you very much. I saw your update. In my case  temperature on the body is not being regulated by a temperature control or any other constant temperature process.Final temperature simply can be calculated by adding the temperature rise to get the final temperature. But, i would like to ask that this calculation is referred to which International standard number for verification purpose.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the above temperature calculations are correct or not?

In some circumstances yes. In others no. The explanation follows.

When in my younger working days I was conducting temperature tests on electrical products to make sure the components and materials used in the products did not exceed their temperature ratings, we had to deal with the issue of using either the temperature rise above the ambient in which we ran the test, or the absolute measured temperature on the component or material, and decide when it was valid to simply subtract the ambient from the measured temperature to determine that rise.

In your calculations you are assuming that body surface temperature rises and falls in proportion to the rise or fall of ambient air temperature where the temperature is being measured. That is generally correct, provided that nothing is limiting the measured temperature other than the ambient.

However, the approach is not valid for components or materials whose temperature is limited by an automatic temperature control or a process such as boiling of water or introduction of liquid at a fixed temperature. Those temperatures will reach some maximum that is limited by the controlling mechanism, not the ambient.

So if there are no temperature limiting controls or processes that are controlling the temperature, you can generally use both calculations, within limits. The test ambient range that we were limited to was 10-40 C. So your example of a 50 C ambient is stretching it a bit.

But if there is a control or process limiting the temperature of the surface to 60.2 C when tested at the 27.2 C ambient, you cannot assume the same temperature rise of 33 C when tested at the 50 C ambient. The maximum temperature will still be 60.2 C for a temperature rise of 10.2 C, not 33 C.

UPDATE:

Based on your latest edits, I think you may be asking if it is possible to predict the temperature on the body in the 50 C ambient based on the temperature rise in the 27.2 C ambient.

Based on my answer it may or not be so. As long at the temperature on the body is not being regulated by a temperature control or some other constant temperature process you can, within limits, simply add the temperature rise to get the final temperature. But if the temperature is limited by some control or process, it doesn't matter what the ambient temperature is. The maximum temperature will be that dictated by the mechanism that controls the temperature.

Hope this helps.